# button_to for file_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, filefield

I feel pretty dumb for asking this, but is it possible to just use a button_to for a file upload as part of a form? I want to create a custom "upload file" button. I would just use the good ol' file_field, but apparently you can't customize that with CSS (or rather are limited to what you can customize). I'm currently using CarrierWave to upload multiple files. I would ideally like to use something form_for based. I'm uploading multiple files that have a has_many relationship in a nested form.

Is there a cleaner approach that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at http://swfupload.org/ for fully custom looking file buttons which would allow you to do what you need and also show upload progress etc. The actual standard browser file_field is pretty crappy and in most browsers does not allow much customization.

Comment: Thanks @ADAM. I'll look into the Do you happen to know if the SWFUpload library is compatible with CarrierWave?

Comment: Sure, it will definitely work as your controller is the glue between the two, adn swfupload passes the same params as a standard html form. watch out for cookies if you are using authentication